# PHP 'nothing' character

Tags: php, string, variables

I like embedding variables in strings - `"I like $verb $noun in strings!"`

But then I was designing a database access script:

```
$sqlfragment = "SELECT * from " . $databasetableprefix . "_user";
```

Lovely. But what happened to my embedding variables in strings?!

I want to do something like this:

```
$sqlfragment = "SELECT * from $databasetableprefix_user";
```

But that will be interpreted as from the variable `$databasetableprefix_user`.

So I would use a space:

```
$sqlfragment = "SELECT * from $databasetableprefix _user";
```

But spaces aren't allowed in database table names, so that won't work.

(What I want is this resulting string: `"SELECT * from cc_user"`, if `cc` is the prefix.)

Can I create this string using variable embeds? Perhaps a sort of 'nothing' character, that will stop PHP from thinking it is part of the variable name, but not carry through to the SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$sqlfragment = "SELECT * from {$databasetableprefix}_user";
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the variable in {} like so:

$sqlfragment = "SELECT * from {$databasetableprefix}_user";

Answer (score 2):

You have to use curly brackets to tell PHP where the variable name begins and ends, as [described in detail in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

```
$sqlfragment = "SELECT * from {$databasetableprefix}_user";
```

Also, be very careful using variables to generate SQL statements, as it can easily become a security risk if you don't carefully track the source of your variables or validate their values.